# How to decode the following crypt

Tags: java, encryption, decode

I am new to programming and java. I am still learning java. I was solving a crypt(in java) which was provided to me with the constraints below:

> > Input:
> >     wrien
> >
> > Output: erwin
> >
> > How the crypt is encoded: Remove the median letter of the word form the original word and append it to the end of the word until there are no letters left.There is one more condition **if the word length is even, then the left letter of median is chosen**.
> >
> > In the above case **'w'** is the median of the String so it is appended at the **start** and so on.

I somehow managed to encode the String i.e. converted **erwin** to **wrien** but I am not able to decode it. I have tried various ways but they went in vein.
Here is what I tried:[**EDITED ACCORDING TO @Talex's answer**]

```
   String temp = "";
    int i = 0;
    if(text.length() % 2 != 0){
    while(i < text.length()){
        if((i + 1) % 2 == 0)
            temp = text.charAt(i) + temp;
        else
            temp = temp + text.charAt(i);

        i++;
    }
    System.out.println(temp);
    }
    else{//Here it is failing }
```

Please help me to understand to decode the crypt(I am a beginner in programming so apologies if question is not up to the standards but I am totally stuck on the problem).

Thank you

Comment: 1) First you say: "Remove the median letter [...] and append it to the end". But then you also say: "'w' is the median [...] so it is appended at the start". So, what is the exact requirement? 2) You did not show us any code accompanied by an explanation where exactly in your code you got stuck. At this point, your question is both, unclear and too broad.

Comment: What exactly did you try (code)? Maybe we can point out your mistakes.

Comment: @Seenlenvirtuose this is what I was provided with and I had to write the code to encode and decode.I was able to encode the String but not able to decode it. So I mentioned both ways. And I mentioned that I just want to kknow the logic to decode it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get temp variable and initialize it with empty string.

For each letter:

- even letter prepend to temp string.
- odd letter append to temp string.

Code snippet:

```
String tmp = "";
bool flag = true;
for(char c : input.toCharArray()) {
   if(flag) {
      tmp = c + tmp;
   } else {
      tmp = tmp + c;
   }
   flag = !flag;
}
```

Comment: Thanks @talex. Just one query how to **prepend** the temp String as you mentioned in java. I am still a beginner in java so sorry for that

Comment: Prepend: temp = x + temp; Append: temp = temp + x;

Comment: Thanks! arminb I will try this solution

Comment: That is one most efficient technique Sir(@talex). +1 for that.